# How do you put a User Name/Password in JSON format to be used to set XHR reques header

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, request-headers

In Below example, if i use username and password, then anyone can see it in page source.  Is there any solution to hide the username and password or can we put credentials in `json` or `xml` file and access it to set it in header, if yes please let us know the solution.

```
$.ajax({     type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    url: "external domain URL",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,

    beforeSend: function(xhr) {

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username" + ":" + "Password"));
        xhr.withCredentials = true;

},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode username and password into a text and use that text, but this is dangerous and unfeasible, because that way if someone manages to decode it for some reason, then it will be a huge security leak. And if the server accepts an encoded text, that would also be a security leak, so you should avoid this kind of approach, unless you use some temporary tokens, but that would only reduce, but not eliminate the risk.

Instead, it would be much better if you had a page, which would work as follows:

- when the data is needed, a request is sent to the server to gather the username and password
- the server will respond with an encoded variation of these data
- the client-side would decode this
- the client-side will send the request

Also, you could use your server as a proxy, that is, send all the requests to your own server instead of the target server and the server on its turn will forward the request to the target server and the response to the client-side. This would be even better.